# How to find whether a GitHub release tag is pre-release in git?

Tags: git, github, release

While creating the release in github, i have checked the checkbox for pre-release. So in the releases page this tag is marked as pre-release. (with a red color label)

now I am checking out the release to local a

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout -b release-v1.0 release-v1.0
```

now I want to know if the release is a pre-release or not in the local machine.
Is there a command for doing this this?

[image]

Comment: What checkbox? What release page? Git doesn't have checkboxes and pages.

Comment: Which tool are you using which has a "prerelease" checkbox? This is not a feature of Git itself. Perhaps you are asking about Github, which seems to have this: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/ seems to have pertinent documentation.

Comment: @tripleeeI have added the screenshot showing the check box

Answer (score 9):

GitHub Releases are an additional feature on top of git tags. Same as for Pull Request, Issues, and Forks, there is no such concept in git.

When you create a release a new git tag will be created with the same name. But all the properties like

- Release name
- Description
- Pre-release satus

Are attached to the release, not to the tag.

You can poll [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/) for an additional info:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases/:id

{
 ...
  "prerelease": false
}
```

You can use command-line wrapper `hub` https://github.com/github/hub which will hide http calls for you.

Some commands like [`hub release show`](https://github.com/github/hub/blob/master/commands/release.go) should work for you.

Comment: other than accessing the api directly, in my local branch can i refer to any variables or something?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you hit the rate limit (I am working in a large software shop) so it's almost impossible to use API requests (without authorization). My Goal was was to check is get the last stable release into our ci/cd pipeline.

```
function get_recent_stable_relese(){
    URL=$(curl -Ls -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} $1)
    VERSION=$(basename ${URL})
    if [[ -z $VERSION ]]; then
        exit 1;
    fi
    echo $VERSION
    exit 0;
}

BOX_LATEST_RELEASE=http://github.com/box/box-content-preview/releases/latest
echo $(get_recent_stable_relese ${BOX_LATEST_RELEASE})
```

so `latest` becomes last release version which you can use to checkout code.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: requires prior authentication via `gh`, or you will get an error.*

GitHub's own helper CLI (`gh`), does display this, when using `gh release list`:

```
$ gh release list -L 10 -R intel/llvm
TITLE                   TYPE         TAG NAME            PUBLISHED
DPC++ daily 2023-10-17  Pre-release  nightly-2023-10-17  about 23 hours ago
DPC++ daily 2023-10-16  Pre-release  nightly-2023-10-16  about 1 day ago
DPC++ daily 2023-10-15  Pre-release  nightly-2023-10-15  about 2 days ago
DPC++ daily 2023-10-14  Pre-release  nightly-2023-10-14  about 3 days ago
DPC++ daily 2023-10-13  Pre-release  nightly-2023-10-13  about 4 days ago
DPC++ daily 2023-10-06  Pre-release  nightly-2023-10-06  about 11 days ago
DPC++ daily 2023-10-05  Pre-release  nightly-2023-10-05  about 12 days ago
DPC++ daily 2023-10-04  Pre-release  nightly-2023-10-04  about 13 days ago
DPC++ daily 2023-10-03  Pre-release  nightly-2023-10-03  about 14 days ago
DPC++ daily 2023-10-02  Pre-release  nightly-2023-10-02  about 15 days ago
```